# Setting hash values from array

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
row = {
            'name' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'auth' => '',
            'https' => '',
            'cors' => '',
            'url' => ''
        }
```

and I also have an array:

```
["Cat Facts", "Daily cat facts", "No", "Yes", "No", "https://example.com/"]
```

How can I grab the array elements and set them as values for each key in the hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `row` is your hash and `values` is your array

```
row.keys.zip(values).to_h
 => {"name"=>"Cat Facts", "description"=>"Daily cat facts", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"No", "url"=>"https://example.com/"}
```

It works if they are in the right order, of course

Answer (score 2):

```
h = { 'name'=>'',
      'description'=>'',
      'auth'=>'',
      'https'=>'',
      'cors'=>'',
      'url'=>'' }

arr = ["Cat Facts", "Daily cat facts", "No", "Yes", "No",
       "https://example.com/"]
```

```
enum = arr.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Cat Facts", "Daily cat facts", "No",
  #                  "Yes", "No", "https://example.com/"]:each>

h.transform_values { enum.next }
  #=> { "name"=>"Cat Facts",
  #     "description"=>"Daily cat facts",
  #     "auth"=>"No",
  #     "https"=>"Yes",
  #     "cors"=>"No",
  #     "url"=>"https://example.com/" }
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each) can be used in place of [Kernel#to_enum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-to_enum).

If `arr` can be mutated `enum.next` can be replaced with `arr.shift`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the hash and the array:

```
row = { 'name' => '', 'description' => '', 'auth' => '', 'https' => '', 'cors' => '', 'url' => '' }
val = ["Cat Facts", "Daily cat facts", "No", "Yes", "No", "https://example.com/"]
```

One option is to use [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) while transforming the values of the hash:

```
row.transform_values!.with_index { |_, i| val[i] }
row
#=> {"name"=>"Cat Facts", "description"=>"Daily cat facts", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"No", "url"=>"https://example.com/"}
```

The bang `!` changes the original Hash.